# Is plasma an intermediate stage of matter?

Tags: plasma-physics, states-of-matter, matter

Can it truly be called a stable state? Fire is stable while it has fuel but isn't it really just a transition point for solid to gas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a plasma a distinct phase of matter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79426/)

Comment: Plasma is perfectly stable under the right thermodynamic conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The question as you have posed it in the title has been asked before - as noted above in the comments.

But not addressed is your implied question of wheter a fire is a plasma or not. Typically there are two types of plasma - one is where the temperature is so hot (~10,000 K or more) that a significant fraction of the atoms/molecules present are ionized. The other is where a significant ionization fraction is caused by passing an electric current through a gas at low temerpatures (typically room temp to 500 K or a bit more). The first type can be a 'stable state', but the second type is never a 'stable state'.

Fire can generally conduct electricity, but it may just be an ionized gas rather than a plasma. Finally if it is consuming fuel then it is not a 'stable state' or at least certainly not at equilibrium.

Comment: I know very little about physics but from what you say plasma cannot exist without induced energy. The duplicate said plasma will form form at either very hot or absolute zero temps. So will everything return to plasma when the universe reaches absolute zero?

Comment: @user1894167 - I am not sure about absolute zero, but apart from that a plasma needs energy either just from the temperature it is and the kinetic energy it has or from an electric current passed through it to sustain it.