# Plasma and Stars

Tags: astrophysics, stars, plasma-physics

I have read that most stars are made mostly of plasma.

My questions in this statement are:

1. Are there stars not made of plasma?
2. In what percentage stars are made of plasma?

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12760/140434

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Are there stars not made of plasma?

.....

> [Plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) is an electrically neutral medium of unbound positive and negative particles (i.e. the overall charge of a plasma is roughly zero). It is important to note that although the particles are unbound, they are not ‘free’ in the sense of not experiencing forces. When a charged particle moves, it generates an electric current with magnetic fields; in plasma, the movement of a charged particle affects and is affected by the general field created by the movement of other charges.

For more details see [this link](http://www.opencourse.info/astronomy/introduction/08.matter_phases/) too.

A basic effect of the motion of charges is that electromagnetic radiation is created, i.e. light and thus stars certainly have plasma because they are called stars for being  stationary sources of light in the night sky, in contrast to planets. The sun in the center of the solar system is a star and allows us to study the composition of stars, including the evident plasma.

......

> *Our Sun, and all of the other stars*, are made of plasma, much of interstellar space is filled with a plasma, albeit a very sparse one, and intergalactic space too.

[note that "all other stars is not really correct in this wiki link. see below]

Stars that are not wholy plasma are [neutron stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star):

> A neutron star is the collapsed core of a large (10–29 solar masses) star. Neutron stars are the smallest and densest stars known to exist.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) With a radius on the order of 10 km, they can, however, have a mass of about twice that of the Sun. They result from the supernova explosion of a massive star, combined with gravitational collapse, that compresses the core past the white dwarf star density to that of atomic nuclei.

....

> Neutron stars that can be observed are very hot and typically have a surface temperature around 6×10^5 K.

They are [complex stars](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/pulsar.html).

Also very large stars that become [supernovae](http://hipacc.ucsc.edu/Lecture%20Slides/2011ISSAC/Ott.pdf), and in general the whole spectrum in the [evolution of stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_evolution) has stars which are not wholly plasma.

To be visible stars, they have to emit light so that their outer shell must be [plasma.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/plasma.html)

So plasma in the outer atmosphere is necessary for a star to be visible in the night sky, but there do exist stars that are not wholly plasma. Thanks to DrunkenCodeMonkey for catching  it.

you ask:

> In what percentage stars are made of plasma?

They are mostly [plasma](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/plasma.html), i.e neutral ionized matter, even [the core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core),  because of the very large kinetic energies acquired in the [formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_and_evolution_of_the_Solar_System) from the primordial plasma due to the gravitational attraction .

> The core of the Sun extends from the center to about 20–25% of the solar radius. It has a density of up to 150 g/cm3 (about 150 times the density of water) and a temperature of close to 15.7 million kelvins (K). By contrast, the Sun's surface temperature is approximately 5,800 K.

This very high temperature does not allow nuclei and electrons to stabilize into neutral atoms, and even at that high density the core is a plasma. The temporary formation of neutral nuclei gives spectral lines detectable in the star's spectrum, but the temperatures are so high that no solid core can result. The amount of neutral atoms in a plasma is very small, and is controlled by the [relevant equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation), as was pointed out in the comments.

The planetary masses cooled off enough to acquire a solid core.

Comment: Stars aren't *all* plasma; if they were, we wouldn't have any absorption lines in their spectra (which, in the visible range, are created primarily by neutral or only partially ionized gas).

Comment: @probably_someone  that is why I am talking of "stable nuclei", they form and are reexcited  into ionized state.

Comment: Not all of them, though - on the outer layers of stars, there is, for example, a small but significant quantity of neutral hydrogen, which is where we get the Lyman, Balmer and Paschen absorption lines for hydrogen in stellar spectra.

Comment: @probably_someone but if you get the lines it means they are getting excited and deexcited all the time. The mechanism is  a small part of the light released

Comment: Yes, but the position of the dynamic equilibrium is such that there is a non-negligible amount of unexcited gas is present. See the Saha equation, which describes this equilibrium position: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation

Comment: @probably_someone  this goes into the dynamics of plasma, which is not part of the question, imo

Comment: It does, but only to prove to *you* that your claims are incorrect. I already correctly answered the question below, without introducing these.

Comment: @probably_someone Maybe. But that's really going into the fact that phases of matter are just an abstraction. Is an empty bottle full of gas? Well, not really. There's a tiny amount of liquid as well (mostly water, I'd guess) - as some parts of the contents liquidise, others vapourise again. But we usually don't need to account to that. It's the same with plasma. How much mass of the Sun can be considered to be non-plasma on average compared to the total mass of the plasma? Is it important? Sure, in solar spectroscopy. That's one of the things that inspires you to think deeper :)

Comment: Well, the reason I mention it is because stellar spectroscopy is literally one of the only ways we know anything about stars at all. In that way, we always need to account for the fact that the neutral gas is there, and we see it, all the time, whenever we take spectra. So in terms of mass it's not much, but if you assume stars were all plasma, then most of astrophysics gets VERY confusing VERY quickly.

Comment: @probably_someone  Look, if they remain neutral, you will not see them in the spectrum , they have to be excited to see them. So yes, when one sees hydrogen lines one knows there are excitations and deexcitations, but this will happen with the kinetic energy tails of the plasma ions and electrons anyway, even if there are no neutral atoms per se except during the delta(t) time of  excitation and deexcitation.

Comment: One will have to use the equations you linked to, to see how much is neutral for a delta(t) depending on the temperature and pressure.

Comment: Hydrogen doesn't get ionized in order to produce Balmer absorption lines, it only gets excited. At the surface of the Sun the temperature is 5800 K and virtually all gas is neutral, but as soon as you go a little below the surface, the temperature quickly rises above the ~1e4 K necessary to keep virtually all the hydrogen ionized. Anna is right that the fraction of neutral gas in the whole star is extremely small, and @probably_someone is right that this extremely small fraction is quite important in astronomy. Now hug.

Comment: Neutron stars have no plasma, only tightly packed neutrons and possibly a quark-gluon "plasma" at the core. White dwarfs have no plasma, and are maintained not by radiation pressure but by electron degeneracy pressure. Brown dwarves can be cool enough that there is no plasma, only superheated gases.

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey you are correct . I will edit

Comment: edited correcting, there are stars that are not wholly plasma @pela

Comment: @DrunkenCodeMonkey The *majority* of a neutron star is in the form of a fluid consisting of about 98% neutrons (by number) and 1% each of protons and electrons and would therefore could be described as a plasma. White dwarfs can *only* be described as a plasma when they are reasonably young and hot, consisting of positively charged nuclei and degenerate electrons. Brown dwarfs are no different to stars in terms of their interiors being almost entirely plasma.

Comment: "To be visible stars, they have to emit light so that their outer shell must be plasma." What new physics is this?

Comment: Plasmas do not need to consist *entirely* of charged particles, Hot plasmas are almost totally ionised whilst cold plasma are mostly neutral particles. The entire Sun, even the photosphere, can be described as a plasma. What is required for this to be a proper answer is a calculation of the Debye screening length and comparison with the number density of electrons or the plasma parameter. The definition of a plasma is not just that it is ionised.

Answer (score 9):

1. No, I think what is meant here is that in addition to containing lots of plasma, all stars also include a bit of neutral gas near their edges (this is where absorption lines in their spectra come from). This is an ambiguity in English - "things are mostly this" can either mean "most things are all this" or "all things are mostly this".
2. Hard to give a value, as it varies based on type of star, environment, and point in its life, but you can't really go wrong assuming that neutral gases are only a tiny fraction of the total mass.